# how to release a build for selenium scripts

Tags: ios, selenium, automation, webdriver

I finished writing Atuomation scripts(using selenium webdriver) for IOS Application.
Now how can i release it to client (Or) how to release a build and how to run scripts once again

Comment: You can share it through commonly accessible repositories using SVN or Git. Client just need to check them out and trigger tests.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is code.  You should follow standards for releasing/branching of code and then setup your client with access to the code.  Since it is code I would recommend creating an instruction doc on how to get the latest and how to execute the code through whatever execution mechanism you guys are using...i.e. unit test framework.